# Merge some .NET tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are questions that are tagged [.net-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) (110), and other questions tagged [.net-framework-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-3.5) (7), [.net-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) (4), [.net-2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-2.0) (2).

Would not to keep [.net-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) as general tag, and use tags like [.net-2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-2.0) for the framework version be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, [.net-framework-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-3.5) has been mapped as a synonym for [.net-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5), thereby ensuring that current and future questions with tag [.net-framework-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-3.5) will be renamed to  [.net-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5).

For other questions, with similar tags, we'll take them as ( and if) they come.

Comment: This solution caused various issues a decade later, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14846/rename-net-core-to-net-and-fix-past-synonyms