# Rename .net-core to .net and fix past synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request, tag-synonyms

In November 2020, Microsoft released .NET 5.0 and the "Core" branding was removed.

Alas, 2011's [Merge some .NET tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2395/merge-some-net-tags) request messed up present times by doing the opposite - removing the word "framework" from what is now only .net framework (which is a **different** product than .net, as .net is its successor while .net framework is not expected to ever get a new version).

So please consider to:

1. Release [.net](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net) from being a synonyms to [.net-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework)
2. Then rename [.net-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) to just [.net](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net)
3. Release [dotnet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dotnet) from being a synonyms to [.net-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework)
4. Then make [dotnet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dotnet) a synonyms to [.net](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net)
5. Release [.net-framework-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-3.5) from being a synonyms to [.net-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5)
6. Then rename [.net-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) to [.net-framework-3.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-3.5)
7. Rename [.net-4.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) to [.net-framework-4.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.0)
8. Rename [.net-4.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) to [.net-framework-4.5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.5)
9. Rename [.net-2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-2.0) to [.net-framework-2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-2.0)

Comment: What did Stackoverflow end up doing with these tags?